# Move to beginning/end of comment in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

In Word (version 14 from Office 2010), when I'm editing a review comment (text that appears in the right margin in the user interface), I want the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to move to the beginning and end of the comment, and not to the beginning and end of the document.

I know how to change keyboard shortcuts, that's not the question. What do I need to bind the keys to? I'm guessing I'd have to write a macro. How do I detect whether the cursor is in a comment or not? When in a comment, how do I move to the beginning/end of the comment?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the shortcut key ALT and down arrow (or ALT and up arrow).  In Word 2010, this steps through comments with cursor at start of comment text, so you could try ALT and either up/down to move to next comment, then reverse option to move back to the comment you want to be at start of.